Create custom QML PdfStyle
I'm developing an application (pdf reader) in QT/QML using PdfMultiPageView control and Qt.Pdf library; I'd like to create a custom highlight for text search (change color, for example). How can I do this?
In Qt documentation there is a type "PdfStyle", with a few properties to change for example, highlighting, but I can't assign an object of this type to any property of PdfMultiPageView; there is no "style" property, as in the following example. How can I apply the custom PdfStyle to my PdfMultiPageView? Thanks
PdfMultiPageView {
        id: mpv
        anchors.fill: parent
        document: doc
        searchString: "example"

        //style: pdfStyle
        //not working!
    
    }

PdfStyle {
    id: pdfStyle
    currentSearchResultStrokeColor: "yellow"
    currentSearchResultStrokeWidth: 2
    selectionColor: "orange"

}


Currently, there is no direct way to access the PdfStyle component within PdfMultiPageView, PdfScrollablePageView, and PdfPageView. This is because PdfMultiPageView contains a PdfStyle component defined internally, and there is no alias pointing to that component.
If you examine the source code, you'll see that the PdfMultiPageView is essentially a straightforward QML file that implements a PDF viewer using base PDF components (such as PdfPageImage, PdfPageNavigator, etc). This means you can create your own implementation and customize it according to your needs.
However, if you don't have the time to go through the customization process, there's a workaround. By inspecting the non-visible children of the PdfMultiPageView, you can find that the PdfStyle is located at resources[1] or data[1]. You can use this to modify the properties of PdfStyle.
In the example below, I assign the second child to the style property, allowing me to change the selectionColor and other attributes.
PdfMultiPageView { 
    property PdfStyle style

    Component.onCompleted: {
        style = resources[1]

        style.currentSearchResultStrokeWidth = 0;
        style.currentSearchResultStrokeColor = 'transparent';
        style.pageSearchResultsColor = '#88fbc320';
        style.selectionColor = '#88006eb1';
    }
}

Nonetheless, I recommend copying and re-implementing the PdfMultiPageView to better suit your needs, as this will likely result in fewer issues when changing its properties.
Perhaps future updates to Qt will enhance the functionality of PdfMultiPageView as well.
